# c# UserTab class creation

Tags: c#, object, tabs

I try to make a class that could interact with a selfmade Tabcontrol, which is composed here of three button and three panel. 
When you click one button it change the activated one and make the panel 
Here is my code.:

```
namespace Tabobject
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Button> TabBtnCtrl1;
    List<Panel> TabPanCtrl1;
    TabControl TabCtrl1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TabBtnCtrl1 = new List<Button>(3);
        TabPanCtrl1 = new List<Panel>(3);
        AddBtnToList();
        AddPanelToList();           
        TabCtrl1 = new TabControl(TabBtnCtrl1, TabPanCtrl1);
        TabCtrl1.SetActiveTab = 1;
    }
    private void AddBtnToList()
    { 
        TabBtnCtrl1.Add(button1);
        TabBtnCtrl1.Add(button2);
        TabBtnCtrl1.Add(button3);        
    }
    private void AddPanelToList()
    {
        TabPanCtrl1.Add(panel1);
        TabPanCtrl1.Add(panel2);
        TabPanCtrl1.Add(panel3);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { TabCtrl1.SetActiveTab = 2; }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ TabCtrl1.SetActiveTab = 3; }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ TabCtrl1.SetActiveTab = 1; }
}

public class TabControl
{
    private List<Button> ListButton;
    private List<Panel> ListPanel;

    public TabControl(   List<Button> _ListButton,
                            List<Panel> _ListPanel)
    {
        ListButton = new List<Button>();
        ListPanel = new List<Panel>();
        foreach (Button Item in _ListButton) { ListButton.Add(Item); }
        foreach (Panel Item in _ListPanel) { ListPanel.Add(Item); }
        while(true){MessageBox.Show("Anything else?");}
    }
    public int SetActiveTab
    {
        set
        {
            int TabIdx = value - 1;
            if (TabIdx > -1)
            {
                foreach (Button item in ListButton) { SetInactBtnFont(item); }
                foreach (Panel item in ListPanel) { item.Visible = false; }
                ListPanel.ElementAt(TabIdx).Visible = true;
                SetActBtnFont(ListButton.ElementAt(TabIdx));
            }
        }
    }
    protected void SetActBtnFont(Button ButtonToSet)
    {
        ButtonToSet.Font = new Font(ButtonToSet.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        ButtonToSet.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    protected void SetInactBtnFont(Button ButtonToReset)
    {
        ButtonToReset.Font = new Font(ButtonToReset.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
        ButtonToReset.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
}
```

}

Is that a good way to do it or could we do it in another manner which would be more clean? The problem with the list is that we have to populate them by hand, but it's an obligation.
I think it's clean but I wanted to know your advice on the subject.

Thanks!!

Comment: is this in WinForm Application ?

Comment: Yes, on VS21010 C#.

Comment: Does the code that you've given us compile and work as desired?

Comment: Why do you asking me that?